# many .js errors on my magento store

Tags: javascript, magento

How can I fix all these errors? I am new in this thing, don`t have much idea where I can start

My store is [my magento store](http://animesexyfigures.com/index.php/)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
at carousel.js:174
at carousel.js:228

Uncaught TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
at observe (prototype.js:5644)
at HTMLDocument._methodized [as observe] (prototype.js:438)
at animesexyfigures.com/:100
```

I tried to replace some files, but nothing seems works.

Comment: We can't help you if we can't see any code. Please show us any relevant code.

Comment: Where is the concerned code segment?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: im using google develop tools to check the errors, i dont know much about coding, i trying to learn something, that is why i ask if someone have a idea from where start to fix those problems

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing common conflicts between jQuery and prototype. You will need to either write jQuery instead of $ throughout magento or you will have to assign jQuery to $j and use $j instead of $ throughout magento. To assign it to $j you must use the below line of javascript, pretty much anywhere.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Which i would add in a custom js file called noconflict.js

To add the file to the frontend you need to add the following code to your local/xml file located in `app/design/frontend/{{PACKAGE}}/{{THEME}}/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>noconflict.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi! thank you, but i checked the js folder and i have already this noconflict.js with the same code, what can be?

Comment: Hi, the file is not being loaded on the frontend, please see the update to my answer how to add it

Comment: Hi, thank you, my local.xml is locate in public_html/app/design/frontend/emphasis/default/layout/local.xml i added the code but i think still not working...

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in my code, i have removed `js/` from inside the `script` tags